# Actionscript to load XML data after period of time

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to put timer function, so the data from XML will be refreshed to flash every 5 seconds? Using some exaples found from internet did  not worked as looks like it caches XML file.

Here is my code:

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("data.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
   xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

   line1.text = xmlData.line1;
   time1.text = xmlData.time1;

}
```

Comment: To avoid the cache problem, you can use something like this for example : `var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("data.xml" + "?" + (new Date().getTime()));` ...

Answer (score 1):

Got it working (morning is better from night). Here is the code:

```
var my_xml_loader:URLLoader;
var timerRefreshRate:Number = 5000;
var fatherTime:Timer = new Timer(timerRefreshRate, 0);
fatherTime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, processXML);
fatherTime.start();
processXML();

function processXML(event:Event = null):void{

    my_xml_loader = new URLLoader();
    var cacheBuster:String = "?"+(new Date()).time.toString();
    my_xml_loader.load(new URLRequest("your_url"+cacheBuster))
    my_xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadvars);

}

function loadvars (e:Event = null):void{
   var my_xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data); 
   line1.text = my_xml.line1;
   time1.text = my_xml.time1;

}
```